# LTspice - auto-transformer impedance ratio

Tags: rf, ltspice, impedance-matching, spice, autotransformer

Can you please clarify what formula is used by LTspice to calculate the auto-transformer impedance transfer ratio for the equivalent circuits below?

[image]

Both circuits resonate on the same frequency. I expected R1/R2 = Lp / Ls, where Lp = L1 + L2 + 2M and Ls = L1 + M, but this is not the case. It seems that SPICE calculates R1/R2 = 10.

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

$$\frac{R1}{R2} = \left(\frac{L1+L2+2M}{L1+M}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{814u + 231u+2 \times264.51u}{231u + 264.51u}\right)^2 = 10.1$$

so for frequency response curves to match R1 = 2000*10.1 = 20181ohm

Comment: I still do not understand why R1/R2 = (Lp/Ls)^2 and not to Lp/Ls. Can you please clarify.